JavaFX: Resizing buttons inside a grid pane
I created this prototype of a calculator using scene builder, that works perfectly fine with the set width and height (376x752) but I'm getting many problems while trying to resize the window. How can I prevent that the window cannot be smaller than my already set width and height? Also, when maximizing the window, my VBox containing the Label gets resized to fill the whole horizontal space on the screen, however, the operation buttons still on their position. How can I make the buttons enlarge to fill the horizontal space created after maximizing the window? (I'm trying achieve a behaviour similar to Windows calculator)
<AnchorPane minHeight="752.0" minWidth="376.0" style="-fx-background-color: #17181a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="muri.calc.HelloController">
   <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="138.0" minHeight="130.0" minWidth="312.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="34.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="32.0">
      <children>
         <Label fx:id="resultadoTexto" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="82" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="WHITE">
            <font>
               <Font size="48.0" />
            </font>
         </Label>
      </children>
   </VBox>
   <!-- Grid for Buttons -->
   <GridPane hgap="20" layoutX="32" layoutY="670" prefWidth="310.0" vgap="14" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="32.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="34.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="32.0">
      <Button fx:id="quadradoBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="n²" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button fx:id="porcentBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="\%" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button fx:id="raizBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="√" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <!-- First Row -->
      <Button fx:id="acBotao" minHeight="31.0" minWidth="62" text="Ac" />
      <Button fx:id="dividirBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button fx:id="multiplicarBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="*" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Button fx:id="subtrairBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

      <!-- Second Row -->
      <Button fx:id="seteBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Button fx:id="oitoBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Button fx:id="noveBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

      <!-- Third Row -->
      <Button fx:id="quatroBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Button fx:id="cincoBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Button fx:id="seisBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Button fx:id="somarBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

      <!-- Fourth Row -->
      <Button fx:id="umBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <Button fx:id="doisBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <Button fx:id="tresBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

      <!-- Fifth Row -->
      <Button fx:id="alterarBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="+/-" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Button fx:id="zeroBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Button fx:id="decimalBotao" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Button fx:id="igualBotao" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Button fx:id="apagarBotao" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="54.0" minHeight="31.0" minWidth="62" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="⌫" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
      <columnConstraints>
         <ColumnConstraints />
         <ColumnConstraints />
         <ColumnConstraints />
         <ColumnConstraints />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
         <RowConstraints />
      </rowConstraints>
   </GridPane>
</AnchorPane>

Set 376x752 size
After resizing the window
I've already tried to change the grid panes row's percent width and hgrow but it didnt work.
sorry for my bad english btw

sorry for my bad english btw I see no problem with your English. Grammar and spelling are completely correct.

A recent question on laying out a calculator in a grid.  Perhaps it will help you.

I would recommend not hard-coding any sizes or positions (no min/pref/max height/width or layoutx/y set to hard-coded values). Then use the layout panes to position things in the logical layout you want. See the official tutorial and the "Next" page from there. (Those are in Java, not FXML, but all the concepts are the same.) For example, your AnchorPane has two child nodes, positioned one below the other, so replace it with a VBox, and then you can remove the layoutX/Y from the VBox and GridPane.

Similarly, there are enough GridPane properties to allow you to control exactly how you want the grid laid out without setting minimum widths of each component, etc. See the second page of the previously-mentioned tutorial for some hints, as well as the GridPane docs.

I have modified your FXML, and I believe the properties you need to adjust are on all the buttons. You should set hgrow and vgrow to SOMETIMES, and also set the maxWidth and maxHeight to MAX_VALUE.
Additionally, I modified the top anchor of the GridPane to stop the buttons from moving above the VBox and also removed the hard-coded width and height from the buttons.
Here is the modified FXML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="752.0" minWidth="376.0" style="-fx-background-color: #17181a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="muri.calc.HelloController">
    <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="138.0" minHeight="130.0" minWidth="312.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="34.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="32.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="138.0">
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="resultadoTexto" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="82" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="WHITE">
                <font>
                    <Font size="48.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
        </children>
    </VBox>
    <!-- Grid for Buttons -->
    <GridPane hgap="20" layoutX="32" layoutY="670" prefWidth="310.0" vgap="14" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="32.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="34.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="32.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="295.0">
        <Button fx:id="quadradoBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="n²" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="porcentBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="\%" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="raizBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="√" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <!-- First Row -->
        <Button fx:id="acBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="31.0" minWidth="62" text="Ac" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="dividirBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="multiplicarBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="*" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="subtrairBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />

        <!-- Second Row -->
        <Button fx:id="seteBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="7" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="oitoBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="noveBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />

        <!-- Third Row -->
        <Button fx:id="quatroBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="4" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="cincoBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="seisBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="somarBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />

        <!-- Fourth Row -->
        <Button fx:id="umBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="doisBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="tresBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />

        <!-- Fifth Row -->
        <Button fx:id="alterarBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="+/-" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="zeroBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="decimalBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62" minWidth="62" text="." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="igualBotao" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="62.0" minWidth="62" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <Button fx:id="apagarBotao" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="54.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="31.0" minWidth="62" text="⌫" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.hgrow="SOMETIMES" GridPane.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints />
            <ColumnConstraints />
            <ColumnConstraints />
            <ColumnConstraints />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
            <RowConstraints />
        </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
</AnchorPane>


"and removed the hard-coded width and height from the buttons". Those hard-coded sizes are still there, which prevents resizing down. Using the AnchorPane could still cause overlap issues if, for example, the user had system preferences set to a bigger font.

Thank you for pointing that out! You're absolutely right. I only removed the prefWidth and prefHeight values and set the maxWidth and maxHeight to Double.MAX_VALUE, but there are still other hard-coded sizes.

Some general tips for creating layouts in JavaFX that behave in an intuitive way when the window is resized:

Do not hard code any positions or sizes. This means not setting layoutX or layoutY at all, and not setting minWidth, prefWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, prefHeight, or maxHeight to any fixed numeric values. (It is sometimes useful to set maxWidth or maxHeight to Double.MAX_VALUE (or "Infinity" in FXML), or to set any of these to the sentinel values Region.USE_PREF_SIZE or Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE.)
Use layout panes to control the position of nodes. Different layout panes will position the nodes according to different strategies, and will recompute the layout if the amount of space available changes. You should choose the strategy depending on how you want the layout to respond if the user resizes the window (or the layout otherwise needs to be recomputed).
The official layout tutorial and its subsequent page document the available layout panes and how to use them. (While that tutorial is old, all of it is still applicable. The code examples are in Java, not FXML, but the concepts are identical.)
Avoid AnchorPane and StackPane except for very basic layouts (just with a small number of leaf nodes, i.e. no other panes, as their children). These do very minimal layout and are really just for combining a small number of controls in very specific ways.

Your main layout is an AnchorPane, which has a VBox and then a GridPane manually positioned below it. The correct layout pane for positioning one thing below another is a VBox, so I replaced the AnchorPane with a VBox. You want both child nodes (the VBox with the label and the GridPane) to span the full width of the main layout, so I set fillWidth to true.
In the grid pane, you have four columns which you want to be equal width. You can achieve this with four ColumnConstraints objects with percentWidth set to 25. You have seven rows and it appears you want the top row to be half the height of the remaining rows. This is a bit trickier, but you need seven RowConstraints objects, with the first having percentHeight set to 100.0/13 and the rest having percentHeight set to 2*100.0/13.
By default, cells in the GridPane will be resized to fill the available space (the default values for ColumnConstraints.fillWidth and RowConstraints.fillHeight are true), up to their maximum size. However, the maximum width and height of buttons, by default, is Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, meaning that they will not grow beyond their preferred size, which in turn defaults to a size just big enough to hold the text and graphic with some padding.
So to let the buttons grow to fill the grid's cells, you should set the maximum width and height to "Infinity".
Here is the resulting FXML. Note there are no hard-coded sizes or positions, other than the maximum sizes mentioned above. The layout responds to resizing by increasing the size of the buttons, as desired.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<VBox fillWidth="true" style="-fx-background-color: #17181a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"/></padding>
    <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" >
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="resultadoTexto" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="82" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="WHITE">
                <font>
                    <Font size="48.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
        </children>
    </VBox>
    <!-- Grid for Buttons -->
    <GridPane hgap="20" vgap="14" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <Button fx:id="quadradoBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="n²" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Button fx:id="porcentBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="\%" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Button fx:id="raizBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="√" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <!-- First Row -->
        <Button fx:id="acBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="Ac" />
        <Button fx:id="dividirBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Button fx:id="multiplicarBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="*" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Button fx:id="subtrairBotao" maxWidth="Infinity"  maxHeight="Infinity" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

        <!-- Second Row -->
        <Button fx:id="seteBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Button fx:id="oitoBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Button fx:id="noveBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

        <!-- Third Row -->
        <Button fx:id="quatroBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Button fx:id="cincoBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Button fx:id="seisBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Button fx:id="somarBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

        <!-- Fourth Row -->
        <Button fx:id="umBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Button fx:id="doisBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Button fx:id="tresBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

        <!-- Fifth Row -->
        <Button fx:id="alterarBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="+/-" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Button fx:id="zeroBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Button fx:id="decimalBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="." GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Button fx:id="igualBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Button fx:id="apagarBotao" maxWidth="Infinity" maxHeight="Infinity" text="⌫" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25" />
            <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25" />
            <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25" />
            <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.6" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.4" />
        </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
</VBox>

and here is a test harness for it:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CalcTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 376, 752);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }
}

The result is

and on resize it looks like

This might not be exactly what you need, but you can modify the layout settings as needed. Refer to the links above and the Javadocs for the relevant layout classes (GridPane, VBox, and the support classes ColumnConstraints, and RowConstraints).

but if i don't hard-code the elements' positions and sizes, how do i define a default size for them or where they should be placed in the root element? i'm sorry if i sound dumb, but i'm just starting to use JavaFX and don't have much experience in building interfaces.

@Murilo See the example I posted. It does not hard code any positions or sizes. Read the documentation for the layout panes I linked in hint #3 in the answer. The layout panes (GridPane in this case) dynamically size and position the elements for you.

@Murilo, you can define no default size, and the controls will assume their own default size and fill available space according to the layout panes used and any constraints placed on them.  You may wish to set some overall default initial size for the root pane or scene if the default assumed is not the size you want, but try without it first and, in general, keep any default sizes set to a minimum and at the highest level pane (or the scene itself) as possible.
